# Exponentially grow range <input>

Tags: javascript, html, math

Basically, I have a `<input type="range" ...>` that I want to divide into four parts.

1. Goes from 0 to 10 000; `step=1000`
2. Goes from 10 000 to 100 000; `step=10 000`
3. Goes from 100 000 to 1 000 000; `step=100 000`
4. Goes from 1 000 000 to 1 000 000 000; `step= 10 000 000`

I figured to manipulate the range would be rather easy, but somehow I need the equivalent of what would be four different `min` and `max` in a single range input. I understand this can probably be done with some logarithmic or exponential formula, but math isn't really my strength.

[image: How I want my input range to work]

I am in a React environment, but I don't particularly need to be spoon-fed code, just a vague idea of how to do this.

Comment: I feel like this is a perfectly fine question to ask and I get downvoted to hell. Directly from the help center `However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very basic idea will be split you range for 4 pieces and have min value as 0, max value as 37, and step is 1. Whenever you will do a change multiply your value by your custom step value:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  
  if (this.value <= 10){
   output.innerHTML = this.value * 1000;
  } else if (this.value > 10 && this.value <= 19) {
   output.innerHTML = (this.value - 9) * 10000;
    
  } else if (this.value > 19 && this.value <= 28){
   output.innerHTML = (this.value - 18) * 100000;
  } else {
   output.innerHTML = (this.value - 27) * 1000000;
  }
}
```

```css
.slider{ 
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="37" value="0" step='1' class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
```